# Objective C Blocks cannot return

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks

I really don't understand how to handle asynchronous requests.

I have this method

```
- (NSString *)getUserID:(void(^)(NSString *result))handler {
    __block NSMutableString *returner = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    [TClient downloadUserID:^(NSString *getIt){
        //NSLog(getIt);
        returner = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%@", getIt];
        handler(returner);
    }];
    return @"getIt, or what I just handled - returner";
}
```

and I want to return `getIt`. How? Where? Why isn't it letting me just do it?

Comment: An asynchronous request doesn't end/complete when the method returns. That's the very definition. You have to handle the result in the completion block.

Comment: Where is the completion point?

Comment: Sorry, I meant completion block.

Comment: It would help if we knew what you were wanting to use `getIt` for.

Comment: It makes no sense to have your `getUserID:` method have a return value. The value will be obtained, eventually, through the completion handler.

Comment: (Also, pro tip: do `[NSMutableString stringWithString:getIt]` instead of a format string to create a mutable string out of a immutable string)

Comment: `getUserID` gives the string from a method that downloads an HTML page to a parser (in different class) to parse the string for a userID

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modify the method:

```
- (void)getUserID:(void(^)(NSString *result))handler {
    [TClient downloadUserID:^(NSString *getIt){
        if(handler) {
            handler(getIt);
        }
    }];
}
```

Since there's an asynchronous network request, the method can not return the result. You should handle result at handler's block.

```
[self getUserID:^(NSString *result) {
    NSLog(@"%@", result); // log user's ID
    someObject.userID = result; // and pass it to the other object
}];
```

Comment: 1) Rename the method - the `get` prefix isn't appropriate. 2) Get rid of the needless `stringWithFormat`. 3) Why a mutable string?

Comment: Mutable string was a result of copy-pasting sources from the question :)

Comment: I'm trying to pass the string that `downloadUserID` gives to another class. So I think it needs to `return` the string, not just log it

Comment: Pass it from the handler

Comment: Log is just an example of what you can do with returned NSString object. Actually, you can pass it to another object.

Comment: What object could I use? Like one defined outside the block?

Comment: You can use any object accessible out of the block. Since the handler's block runs on main thread it's a thread-safety approach.

Comment: So I created a property of client called userID, assigned `result` to `client.userID`, then I tried to log `client.userID` outside the block, it logged `(null)`. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: That's because all the code inside of the block runs later than the code which goes after the block within the method. You should do all operations inside of the block.

Comment: Ohhhhhhhh. That worked. It makes sense now, it's still processing the `result` value when I try to log it so it seems to be null.

Comment: Yes, exactly. That's a feature of the asynchronous programming.

Comment: But now that I have the value inside the completion block, how do I put it somewhere else? Because it's asynchronous, if I try to use it somewhere it'll just be `null`, right?

Comment: It depends on how you plan to use the value. For example, if you need to update UI then just run update method from the block.

Comment: I want to assign it to a dictionary in another class. So I guess return the value?